# Laravel8 attribute or appends in query where

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, query-builder

I want to reach the record

if in model User

```
class User extends Model {

       protected $fillable = ['last_name','first_name'];

       protected $appends = [
         'full_name',
       ];

       public function getFullNameAttribute(): string
       {
            return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
       }
}
```

in request

```
full_name = 'John Johans';
```

How to get database record if

```
 User::query()->where('full_name',$request->full_name)
```

If I use this record the answer will be an error that full_name does not exist in the database

I would like to use "where" for "appends"

```
User::query()->where(**MY ATTRIBUTE**,$request)->first()
```

it is possible ?

Comment: that  field doesn't exist in the database so you would have to do some type of 'concat' on the database with those 2 fields that actually exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Options:

1. Use `CONCAT` in your `WHERE` clause

```php
User::query()
    ->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) = "?"', [$request->full_name])
    ->get();
```

2. Get all the users and then filter in the resulting `Collection`.

```php
User::cursor()
    ->filter(function ($user) use ($request) {
        return $user->full_name == $request->full_name;
    })
    ->collect();
```

```php
User::cursor()
    ->filter(fn($user) => $user->full_name == $request->full_name)
    ->collect();
```

---

Letting SQL do the filtering (Option 1) is probably the better choice.